# SQL- I need to match all words from one column to all words in other column and vice versa in order to match them

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching, full-text-search

I have two tables with

•Table A:

```
Company name
------------------------
Honeywell  
South east ATM  
Soft graft  
Northwest air force
```

•Table B:

```
Company1_name                   |  Id
----------------------------------------
ATM South east.                 |    1        
Honey tech.                     |    2  
Honey,    Well                  |    3  
Graft, soft.                    |    4  
Air force                       |    5
```

#### I want this result:

```
------------------
3  
1  
4  
5
```

For every row in table A, find a row in table b whose company name value has all the words from table A's value and return the matching ids. If it can't find the record, match the other way round -from table b to table A- like the last record northwest air force- as the word 'northwest air force' is not there in table B, it will find the word 'air force' in table A and will match to 'Northwest air force'

How to design a query for this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Honeywell doesn't actually match honey and well, from the standpoint of whole words. It could be matched in the second pass using partial word matching, but using partial word matching could cause unexpected results with different data if what you really want is only whole word matching. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the problem criteria are inconsistent.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the word 'and'. Can someone please help me to design the query.

Comment: sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. The problem with matching Honeywell wasn't the word 'and'. The problem is that Honeywell is one word and 'Honey and Well' are two words. It can't be matched on a word for word basis, with sql or any other language. It can be matched going back the other way by matching the characters but then it wouldn't come up as the first item in the results and if we did it that way then it would wreck the functionality for matching just word by word for new data. Can you say anything more about the larger context of the problem. What is this for?